# JRockit setting for heap dump on OutOfMemory Error

Tags: java, out-of-memory, jrockit

I understand that there is a setting in Sun JVM for dumping the heap when OM occurs (`-XX:+HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryErro`). Is there any similar setting for JRockit VM or the same setting will work?

Comment: If you have a program which runs out of memory on JRockit, its likely to run out of memory for the same reason on the Sun/Oracle/OpenJDK JVM. i.e. you should be able to reproduce the problem there.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`-XX:+|-HeapDiagnosticsOnOutOfMemoryError`

See [here](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E15289_01/doc.40/e15062/optionxx.htm#BABBBEAJ) for full listing